# How do I get Ubuntu Linux 14.04 to recognize my Kindle Fire HD?

Tags: 14.04, dell, kindle

I already tried gmtp. It doesn't see the device.

I also tried the longer route at itsfoss.com. That method didn't work, either, possibly because 14.04 didn't recognize a couple of the commands. (?)

I have a new Dell Inspiron 15 that it won't work on. Oddly enough, the Dell Inspiron 10 I had automatically loaded the Kindle's hard drive.

I tried reinstalling 14.04. Didn't help.

I'm absolutely dumbfounded. Does anybody have an idea what may be wrong?

Comment: Did you check that your cable is a data-capable one and not just a power cable?  Does the connected Kindle say it's connected to a low power charger when you attach it to the PC?  Did you try other USB ports?

Answer (score 1):

There're 2/3 sides to this, getting the device recognized by the system, mounting the filesystem to transfer files, automounting. For the first, follow the instructions here:

http://www.davidcraddock.net/2014/02/10/kindlefire-hdx-under-ubuntu-12-04/

For the second, to mount, create a mount point (/mnt/kindle) with the right permissions. Mount available mtp devices with "sudo mtpfs /mnt/mtp".

Tell me how you manage the third :) I got it to work on one of my laptops but I forget the method.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MTP